# Can anybody tell me which one will perform better with millions of rows of data in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, subquery, left-join, window-functions

In SQL which one is good:

1. Common Table Exasperation(CTE)
2. Temp table
3. Variable table

When we have 10000000 records in our table and need to sub-query offetch record    LIKE :-

```
WITH cteData AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Product_Id, Variant_Id, Variant_Name, Unit_Price,
        (SELECT GST FROM Product_Details P with(nolock) 
         WHERE V.Product_Id = P.Product_Id) AS GST 
    FROM 
        Variant_Details V with(nolock)
)
SELECT 
    Product_Id, Variant_Id, Variant_Name, 
    SUM(Unit_Price * GST) AS Variant_Total_Price,
    (SELECT SUM(C.Unit_Price * C.GST) FROM cteData C 
     WHERE CD.Product_Id = C.Product_Id) AS Product_Total_Price
FROM 
    cteData CD
GROUP BY 
    Product_Id, Variant_Id, Variant_Name
```

or:

```
SELECT 
    Product_Id, Variant_Id, Variant_Name, Unit_Price,
    (SELECT GST FROM Product_Details P with(nolock) 
     WHERE V.Product_Id = P.Product_Id) AS GST 
INTO 
    #tempData 
FROM 
    Variant_Details V with(nolock)

SELECT 
    Product_Id, Variant_Id, Variant_Name, 
    SUM(Unit_Price * GST) AS Variant_Total_Price,
    (SELECT SUM(C.Unit_Price * C.GST) FROM #tempData C 
     WHERE CD.Product_Id = C.Product_Id) AS Product_Total_Price
FROM 
    #tempData CD
GROUP BY 
    Product_Id, Variant_Id, Variant_Name
```

In both cases - which one is better when there are millions of records in the table?

Comment: Why don't you try and benchmark both? To measure is to know. Without us knowing the details about your table, indices, partitioning and whathaveyou all we can do is provide general statements / assumptions which may not apply to your situation.

Comment: You have provided far too little information to be able to make any kind of assessment. I suggest you run your queries with `explain plan` (or equivalent, you didn't even say which database you are using), and use a profiler that will tell you which parts of the query are taking up the most time.

Comment: you are right @jurez.

Comment: I'm trying both cases and check profiller  but some time it difficult to find the right one because some where first one is batter and some where second is best.

Answer (score 2):

As with all performance questions, you should probably try on your database with your hardware and your data.

That said, I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT v.Product_Id, v.Variant_Id, v.Variant_Name,
       SUM(v.Unit_Price * p.GST) as variant_total_price,
       SUM(SUM(v.Unit_Price * p.GST)) OVER (PARTITION BY v.product_id) as variant_total_price,
FROM Variant_Details V LEFT JOIN
     Product_Details P 
     ON V.Product_Id = P.Product_Id
GROUP BY Product_Id, Variant_Id, Variant_Name;
```

With the right indexes, I would expect this to be faster than other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using joins and window functions rather than CTE and subqueries. This should do what you want, and perform better than both solutions you are looking to compare:

```
select v.product_id, v.variant_id, v.variant_name, v.unit_price, pd.gst
    sum(pd.unit_price * pd.gst) variant_total_price,
    sum(sum(pd.unit_price * pd.gst)) over(partition by v.product_id) product_total_price
from variant_details v
left join product_details pd on pd.product_id = v.product_id
group by v.product_id, v.variant_id, v.variant_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have also used `group by` in your query. When considering millions of records group by will definitely slow down the performance.

I suggest a solution by using `Outer Apply`. Here is the code for it:

```
    SELECT v.Product_Id, v.Variant_Id, v.Variant_Name,
       val.variant_total_price,
       val.variant_total_price OVER (PARTITION BY v.product_id) as product_total_price,
    FROM Variant_Details v 
    OUTER APPLY
    (
      SELECT SUM(v.Unit_Price * p.GST) as variant_total_price
      FROM Product_Details p where v.Product_Id = p.Product_Id
    ) val
```